# problem with html form submit with nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, forms, sqlite, express

I have created a simple register and login application with node.js + express + SQLite DB, I successfully pushed user details of `register.html` to SQLite database but stuck with the sign-in page. I tried to make a simple post request that carries username value and just printed it in the console to check but there is no response when I click on the submit button on `login.html`. Can anyone explain what's happening here?!

**login.html**

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sign in</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylekit.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-box">
    <div class="home">
      <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    </div>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5500/myaction.html" method="post">
      <h1>Sign in</h1>

      <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="uname">
      </div>

      <div class="textbox">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
      </div>
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Sign in">
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('db/database.db');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));


app.post('/database',function(request,response){
   console.log('POST request received at register/database');
  db.run('INSERT into database values(?,?,?,?)',[request.body.firstname,request.body.lastname,
    request.body.password,request.body.cpass],function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            response.status(200).redirect('http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/login.html');
          }
    });
    response.end();
});

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
  res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.firstname + '".');
  res.end();
});

app.listen(8080,function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
 else console.log('server is running');
});
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <input type="button" class="btn" value="Sign in">
> ```

That isn't a submit button. It is a button that does nothing by default (the design intention is that a JS event handler will be bound to it).

Use a submit button instead.

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign in">
```

or

```
<button>Sign in</button>
```

---

These don't match:

> ```
> action="http://127.0.0.1:5500/myaction.html"
> ```

and

> ```
> app.post('/myaction',
> ```

Comment: oh shit !! i didn't noticed that, thanks a lot bro, it works now !!!